# Bash: looping through lines in a file and using the index of each line ('enumerate' equivalent in python)

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file that contains a list of file paths. I want to loop through each line (file path), manipulate the file and store the manipulated file under a new name.

To do this I would like dynamically name the new file under file_$index so that each new file gets saved and not overwritten. Any ideas how to do this? my current code is:

```
for j in $(cat access.txt); do bcftools view $j -include 'maf[0]>0.0 & maf[0]<0.005' -output [FILE_NAME] ; done
```

i do not know how to dynamically change the file name i.e. to be file_$index. This would be equivalent of doing enumerate on a for loop in python. Note I cannot use the existing file path as that will overwrite the existing file which I do not want

In an ideal world i would manipulate the file path ($j) to extract part of the path as a new name. however I am not sure this is possible so file_$index also works.

Comment: A sample input and output would be a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't read lines with for](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

index=1

while IFS= read -ru3 j; do
  bcftools view "$j" -include 'maf[0]>0.0 & maf[0]<0.005' -output "${j}_$index"
  ((index++))
done 3< access.txt
```

---

> In an ideal world i would manipulate the file path ($j) to extract part of the path as a new name.

As for the `"$j"` a [Parameater Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) can be use to manipulate/extract/replace whatever you want/wish with that variable.

- `-ru3` is a shorthand for `-r` `-u 3` It is using the [FD](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FileDescriptor) `3` just in case `bcftools` is [eating stdin](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) , See `help read`
- `((index++))` is an [Arithmetic expression](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) in bash.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for such a clear answer - i also learned about parameter expansion which I used here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can increment your own index with something like this:

```
i=$(( ${i:-0} + 1 ))
```

then your output string can be

```
"$j_$i"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `while read`

```
while read idx fpath; do 
    echo "$(basename $fpath)_$idx.txt"
done <<<$(cat tmp.txt | nl)
```

Result

```
a_1.txt
b_2.txt
c_3.txt
```

For OP's code

```
bcftools view $j -include 'maf[0]>0.0 & maf[0]<0.005' -output "${fpath}_${idx}"
```