# How do i remove whitespace from a string from a list?

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have this bash script that lists all the jobs on jenkins. I have jobs with spaces within them and some without.

```
#!/bin/bash
for job in $(java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL -auth admin:admin list-jobs)
do
    file_name="$(echo "$job" | sed 's/ /-/g').xml"
    echo $file_name
    java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL get-job $job > $file_name
done
```

I have jobs called for example:

- new job
- test-job

When I run this script however I get the following result:

```
new.xml
job.xml
test-job.xml
```

Instead I would like to output:

```
new-job.xml
test-job.xml
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: As the bash tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.", See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73668255/bash-looping-through-lines-in-a-file-and-using-the-index-of-each-line-enumera/73668345#73668345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash for loops splits when they see any whitespace like space, tab, or newline. So, you should use IFS (Internal Field Separator)

If lines end with "\n", try adding `IFS=$'\n'` before the loop (you can use `unset IFS` to reset it later)

You have a lot of examples here: [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash/918931#918931)

Answer (score 2):

Space is also assigned to IFS by default and is respected during word splitting.

There are three common solutions here: First is to set IFS to `$'\n'` temporarily, as already suggested by Atxulo. Second is to use a `while read` loop against a process substitution instance, which is useful for large or indefinite inputs. Third is to use `readarray` which stores all input to an array. This one I believe being most practical to your problem.

```
readarray -t jobs < <(java ...)

for job in "${jobs[@]}"; do
```

Your script also has other issues. First is unnecessary use of sed. Just use `${param//pat/rep}`. You also allow multiple variables to undergo word splitting unnecessarily. Quote them.

Read the Bash manual for details.